# buffer tex editor with two stack

Tags: stack, buffer, text-editor

I am trying to understand this paragraph, if anyone can understand this, can he/she explain me? espacially strong black sentences..

thanks...

> Buffer has to be an array. **Implement two stacks on top of buffer
>   array. One stack grows from left to right and the other stack grows
>   from right to left.**
>
> When a character is inserted, push it to left stack.
>
> When a character is deleted, pop from the right stack.
>
> When cursor is moved to left, pop the top character from left stack
>   and push it to right  stack
>
> When cursor is moved to right, do opposite of left move
>
> get(i): **If i is less than left top then return buffer[i]. If it's more
>   then return buffer[right + i - left]**

Comment: actually i can't understand how to manage two stack with opposite sides ( to left - to right)

Comment: It seems to me the two stacks represent a document together with a cursor. The two stacks are the part before the cursor and the part after the cursor, both growing towards the cursor.

Comment: I m understanding like that, but I can't realize this as a code

Comment: can somebody show this with java code ? i can't implement in my mind this

Answer (score 0):

I had this assignment this semester. Here is my solution, if anyone is still looking:

https://gist.github.com/avindra/6572866